# How to export an applet together with the referenced libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, export

I want a standalone java applet, but I'm unable to export it together with the used libraries, as there is no main method I cannot export a Runnable JAR, so I'm left with Export JAR.
Forgot to mention I'm using ECLIPSE.

Answer (score 3):

The Fat jar eclipse plugin can do that:
get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fjep/) .

However the export runnable jar functionnality might work, it only shows up a warning about the lack of main but since you specify it in the html it should be ok. Moreover a jar generated by fat jar or the runnable export have the exact same architecture of files (in fact the runnable export IS fat jar) so it may be worth a try.